# Tab close prompt working after some delay in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    return (ev.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to close?");
  });
```

The above snippet is being used to prompt on tab close. It is working but only after some delay. i want this to work as soon as i open the web page.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't see from the snippet in which context is this used in React. But if it is, you will have to wait until React loads and component mounts. That's why it won't work in react.

If you can use it outside of React I would advise this:

HTML document executes in Top-Down Approach.

When you execute your HTML Document, it will execute head first and that's where you should put this time sensitive code. Script tag inside head will execute first and set the event listener as earlier as possible.

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        return (ev.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to close?");
      });
    </script>
    ...rest of the code
</head>
```

Something like this...